# Splitting very large working table

Tags: sql-server, c#, entity-framework

I read the good posts [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48176/splitting-a-large-table-to-improve-performance) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87467/at-what-point-should-i-split-or-partition-a-very-large-but-simple-table), but my scenario is a bit different, I cannot consider that older data becomes read-only data because any record in my `Transactions` table can be subject to updates at any time.

The (short?) story is: I have a `Transactions` table that should hold over 2 billions of items in it.
The data is produced by distinct jobs, each job generates its own data into the `Transactions` table. One column is a foreign key: `Transactions.JobId`. This table contain working datasets logically splitted between jobs (jobs are kept in a separate `Jobs` table).

The operations on the `Transactions` table are:

1. `BULK INSERTs` (using C# [SqlBulkCopy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx))
2. `UPDATEs` for single rows (rows get their statuses updated)

As the `Transactions` table gets bigger, we start getting poor performance, even [sql deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx). The hardware won't keep up with the needs, so I am thinking of splitting the table `Transactions` into multiple smaller tables (let's say max of 100M records/table). Then, I can define a "covering view" to aggregate the data when I need to perform some general query. When the first `Transactions1` table is full (contains 100M records), any new jobs will be pointed to store their data into the second table `Transactions2` and so on.

Question is, **do you see this as a feasable approach, is there other options**?
Another one would be an expensive Enterprise license for SQL Server.

PS: Some modules of my C# apps use ADO.NET, other modules make use of EF Code First and Linq2Sql to access the data.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the approximative `Transactions` table structure:

```
PK: [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
FK: [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
FK: [JobId] [int] NOT NULL,
FK: [ItemStatusCodeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
+ other 7 columns
```

(indexes are created for each FK).

The column that is frequently updated is `ItemStatusCodeId` which is a FK that points to another table that holds 10 records only. The update is as simple as it can get:

```
UPDATE Transactions SET ItemStatusCodeId = <value> WHERE Id = <key>
```

Comment: What version and edition is this? There might be other options depending on that

Comment: @TomV I would not like to depend on some version/edition, if possible

Comment: Could you add table structure and samples of the updates you are running?

Comment: @TomV Added some table structure